# Remove the response wrapper from web service response?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services

Is it possible to remove the what appears to be automatic **notificationRequestResponse** node from the response?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  ...
  <soap:Body>
    <notificationRequestResponse xmlns="...">
      <notificationResponse xmlns="...">
        <success xmlns="">boolean</success>
        <fault xmlns="">
          ...
        </fault>
      </notificationResponse>
    </notificationRequestResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to return the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  ...
  <soap:Body>
    <notificationResponse xmlns="...">
      <success xmlns="">boolean</success>
      <fault xmlns="">
        ...          
      </fault>
    </notificationResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want the notificationResponse to be the root of the response!

The WebMethod currently has no logic but:

```
return new notificationResponse()
```

Where is the notificationRequestResponse coming from? I can rename it using WebMethod SoapDocumentMethod(ResponseElementName="new name") but I want it gone. Working to a provided spec and have no choice.

Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer...

SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = [SoapParameterStyle.Bare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapparameterstyle.aspx))